# Extending a class between two Visual Studio C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, header, serversocket

Please have a look at the following diagram

[image]

This is socket programming. `Server` is one VS Project. `Client` is another VS project. But, they both extend one class!!! How can I extend a class between 2 VS applications???? Please help!

Comment: Check my answer to similar question: [Tools for c++ multiplatform projects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15496411/231388)

Comment: @Yousf: Can you do the same answer here with step by step instructions please?

Answer (score 1):

Put the base class in a header file which is visible and accessible to both projects. `#include` that file from those projects and extend the base class.

*In Visual Studio, you can [make a solution which contains projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx).*

Comment: you can include all project

Comment: Can you provide me step by step instructions please?

Comment: @Yohan: It's long, but I put a useful link on my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But There should be only 2 projects. This will make 3 projects right? If it helps, it says 'Pre-processor directives should be embedded '